# Pros & Cons of different ways to create a timer in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, nstimer

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nstimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html):

> There are three ways to create a timer:
>
> 1. Use the `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:invocation:repeats:` or
>      `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:` class
>      method to create the timer and schedule it on the current run loop in
>      the default mode.
> 2. Use the `timerWithTimeInterval:invocation:repeats:` or
>      `timerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:` class method
>      to create the timer object without scheduling it on a run loop. (After
>      creating it, you must add the timer to a run loop manually by calling
>      the `addTimer:forMode:` method of the corresponding NSRunLoop object.)
> 3. Allocate the timer and initialize it using the
>      `initWithFireDate:interval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:` method.
>      (After creating it, you must add the timer to a run loop manually by
>      calling the `addTimer:forMode:` method of the corresponding `NSRunLoop`
>      object.)

What are the pros and cons of the above methods, in terms of:

- performance (memory consumption, etc)
- ease of use (possibility to control/ start/ stop the timer in any point of program)
- thread-safe

Look forward to your reply.